# change order of wordpress widgets

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, sidebar

1. How to change order of widgets when viewing wordpress site from mobile phone? e.g. I need for my невскихрам.срб to show widgets on mobile in the following order (by widget id)

```
- header and menu
- #mh_magazine_posts_large-3
- #mh_magazine_custom_posts-11
- #mh_magazine_youtube-11
- #mh_magazine_youtube-12
- #mh_magazine_youtube-13
- #mh_magazine_youtube-5
- #mh_magazine_posts_grid-5
- #mh_magazine_posts_grid-8
- #mh_magazine_posts_list-5
- footer
```

2. How can I set menu so on mobile phone when I click on text of parent menu it opens submenu items, not just when I click on arrow?

Thanks

Comment: Generally it is recommended to ask questions about programming by providing the steps of your code and pointing out the step in which the issue occurs. Your question is a bit general. Try giving more details or include your code

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
    .container{
    display:flex;
    } 
    #mh_magazine_posts_large-3{
    order:1;
    }
    - #mh_magazine_custom_posts-11{
    order:2
    }... and so on.
}
```

I think what you need is flex and order. but for more details, I need more code, so I can see what to do.

Comment: you can open site and go to inspect element [link](https://невскихрам.срб)